# Terminator - can't create tab with profile and command

Tags: gnome-terminator

Using terminator, I want to create tabs with distinct profiles running a custom command in place of a shell. For example I want to create a tab with distinct colors that executes a custom command like "sudo bash" or "ssh somewhere.local". I can create profiles with colors, and thru the "Command" tab I can select/fill-in "Run a custom command ...", BUT these custom commands only execute when I create a new separate window  using:

```
terminator -p otherprofile
```

Merely changing the profile of an existing tab does not cause the custom command to execute, and there seems no way to create a tab with a selected initial profile.
This sort of thing can be done with gnome-terminal and mate-terminal, btw.

Since these custom-command tabs will be created and eliminated based on need, I don't believe that the terminator 'layout' feature will help.

Answer (score 1):

Workaround: Enable the [Custom Commands Menu](https://gnome-terminator.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins.html#custom-commands-menu) plugin,
create an entry for each profile/command and use

```
terminator --new-tab -p profilename -x your_command
```

to open a new tab with profile and command.

[image: custom commands menu screenshot]

Comment: Kinda hack-y but it does work.  Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work in a way that I find acceptable.   The command "terminator --new-tab -p profilename -x your_command" appears, echo'ed as a shell command,  in the tab where it was initiated.   The command also executes in the context of that tab, which causes a failure when initiated from a sudo or ssh tab.  Thanks tho'.

Comment: Do you know what the context menu's _Profiles_ sub-menu is good for, please? It does nothing when I select a specific profile there (apart from just "selecting" it for the current tab in the sub-menu), but a newly created tab has the default profile selected back.

Comment: @DavidFerenczyRogožan It just switches the profile on the current tab/window. You can also define previous/next shortcuts for that.